# Text size using tikz-cd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I've written this diagram using tikz-cd

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep = huge, column sep = huge]
    & \makebox{Spin($M$)}  \arrow[d, "\Pi", twoheadrightarrow] \\
    U \arrow[ru, "\tilde\sigma", hookrightarrow]  \arrow[r, "\sigma"', hookrightarrow] & \makebox{SO($M$)}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to make symbols near arrows bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! All you need to do is to add `every label/.append style={font=\normalsize}` to make their font size as large as the one of the other nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep = huge, column sep = huge,every label/.append
  style={font=\normalsize}]
    & \makebox{Spin($M$)}  \arrow[d, "\Pi", twoheadrightarrow] \\
    U \arrow[ru, "\tilde\sigma", hookrightarrow]  \arrow[r, "\sigma"', hookrightarrow] & \makebox{SO($M$)}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]